# Windows file starting with dot raises PermissionError?

Tags: python, windows, windows-10, permission-denied

I have a program (written in Python3.6, transformed into an .exe for Windows using cx_Freeze) that uses a lock-file to mark whether a user-login is currently in use, to allow the use of the same login across multiple computers while avoiding possible database corruptions.

The file is created right after the user login is confirmed (and deleted when the user logs out):

```
lockfile = os.path.join(user_dir, ".locked")
with open(lockfile, "w") as _:
    os.utime(lockfile)
```

On my Windows7 Professional machine, this works fine. It also works fine on my local Windows10 test machine.

Now, I have a client on a remote location who is trying to use the program. And apparently, they consistently get a Permission Error: `[Errno 13] Permission denied: '<user_dir>\.locked'`. (Their path seems valid, and the program has no problem *creating* the user_dir, or writing a `config.ini` file to it, so writing privileges on the directory should not be the issue.)

**Do some Windows versions maybe have trouble with files starting with a dot?** Could using an underscore etc. instead help?

The client uses Windows10 (Enterprise) Version 1809 (Build 17763.379).

(It's hard to debug from here, and as I have to recompile the installer after every change, it would be nice to have an idea if this even makes sense... Any other thoughts about potential sources of the problem are welcome, as well!)

Comment: You're missing a quote in the snippet

Comment: Could your user directory be hard-coded in some inappropriate manner?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks for spotting the typo. The user directory is completely fine. :(

Comment: You don't need to open the file before updating the timestamp using os.utime(), though that seems independent of the issue at hand. I don't think this code is the problem, there must be something else going on that's behind the issue.

Comment: You say the user can run the app from multiple machines and you use the lock file to prevent contention. Maybe some of the machines mount the user home directory read-only?

Comment: I think probably the user has set the file attributes as hidden or system. When overwriting such a file, we have to retain the hidden or system attribute(s), else the create is disallowed. This is possible with WINAPI `CreateFileW`, but not with C `_wopen` and thus not with Python `open`.

Comment: The user may have marked the file as hidden to avoid clutter. If you're creating this dot file in the user's profile directory, as in a conventionally hidden file in Unix, then you're going against Windows platform conventions. I recommend that you create the file either in the user's temp directory or a private subdirectory of the user's `%LocalAppData%` directory.

Comment: @SimonHibbs The user in this case only uses one machine, and the access is obviously not read-only, as the same machine created the user directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it really was the starting dot colliding with some (but not all) Windows versions. I created a new version where the file is named "_locked" and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

According to this article, creating filenames starting with dots is only added to Windows 10 1903:

https://www.ghacks.net/2019/02/25/windows-10-1903-support-for-filenames-and-folders-with-beginning-dot-character/

Had similar experience with Windows server 2019 where it was at least impossible to add .files via the file explorer. Workaround was to create the files via PowerShell, though I guess that doesn't really help here. :|

Comment: That patch is to allow the Windows Explorer application to handle files beginning with a dot. The actual filesystem and many other utilities and applications have been able to handle such files for a long time, so I'm not sure that can be the problem.